# How to switch incoming & outgoing mail servers in Postbox Express after switching hosts?

Tags: email, imap, smtp, postbox

I recently had all my websites switched over to another host.  I have e-mails associated with each website, and I'm using Postbox Express.

You'd think it would be easy, but for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to switch servers -- **without adding an entirely new account and losing all of the mail I have saved**.

Is this possible?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!